# Autofac - SingleInstance HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

Have read in various places that HttpClient should be reused rather than a new instance every time.

https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

I am using Autofac on a project.

Would this be a good way of making a single instance of HttpClient available to inject into services?

```
builder.Register(c => new HttpClient()).As<HttpClient>().SingleInstance();
```

Seems to work :)

Comment: So what is your question? (*it appears you answered it yourself on the last 2 lines*)

Comment: Is this good practice really.  I'm very new to DI

Comment: Absolutely, there is nothing wrong with this approach.

Comment: Awesome.  I guess I was just taken by surprise when it worked so easily :)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's perfectly fine if you want one per whole application lifecycle however you might want to configure it different per API endpoint.

```
builder.Register(ctx => new HttpClient() {BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.ipify.org")})
    .Named<HttpClient>("ipify")
    .SingleInstance();

builder.Register(ctx => new HttpClient() { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.postcodes.io") })
    .Named<HttpClient>("postcodes.io")
    .SingleInstance();
```

Then say we have a `PostcodeQueryHandler`

```
public class PostcodeQueryHandler
{
    public PostcodeQueryHandler(HttpClient httpClient) { }
}
```

We'd set up the bindings like

```
builder.Register(ctx => new PostcodeQueryHandler(ctx.ResolveNamed<HttpClient>("postcodes.io")))
        .InstancePerDependency();
```

Comment: I just want to add that `InstancePerDependency()` is the default behavior and you may skip it if you want. [InstancePerDependency Method](https://autofac.org/apidoc/html/B7A3F094.htm)

Comment: @Kevin Smith thanks for the alternative! It's nice to have both of these solutions here in one place.