# How to register service in dependency injection who have a constructor in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, httpclient, autofac

I have the service class and its interface named:

```
IBusApi, BusApi
```

and I can easily register that in Autofac like this

```
builder.RegisterType<BusApi>().As<IBusApi>();
```

but now that I have a constructor for that service that injects `HttpClient`

```
public BusApi(HttpClient http)
{
    _http = http ;
}
```

how can I register that service in DI?

Considering it has a constructor

Comment: Have you reviewed the documentation? https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/registration.html#register-by-type - seems pretty straight-forward.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is the same for all DI/IOC libraries.

For the Type you register (here `BusApi`). All types in the constructor of that type must also be registered/resolved in the DI container (here `HttpClient`).

So you can do a `builder.RegisterType<HttpClient>()` or `builder.RegisteInstance(new HttpClient(..) )`.

Regarding registering `HttpClient` you might read this also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.1&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-2.0

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to register for all types in the constructor in the DI container.

So you can resolve your problem like this

```
builder.Register(c => new HttpClient()).As<HttpClient>();
```

Read the following link to have a better understanding

- [How to register typed httpClient service with autofac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58791239/how-to-register-typed-httpclient-service-with-autofac)
- [Autofac - SingleInstance HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394426/autofac-singleinstance-httpclient)

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @alirezas