# When building my Autofac container, how do I include previously registered types as parameters in other registered types?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, autofac

Consider the following:

```
        public static IContainer Configure()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            // Register a named HttpClient instance as a singleton.
            builder.Register(_ =>
            {
                var client = new HttpClient
                {
                    MaxResponseContentBufferSize = int.MaxValue,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(50)
                };

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Keep-Alive", "3600");
                return client;
            })
            .SingleInstance();

            builder.Register(l => new RandomObject(new HttpClient, "randomString")).As<IRandomObject>();


            return builder.Build();
        }
```

When registering my `RandomObject`, how do I replace that `new HttpClient` instance in my previously registered `HttpClient`? Failing that, is there a way new-up the `HttpClient` parameter so that it has the same settings as the previously registered one?

Comment: i think your question is duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50394426/autofac-singleinstance-httpclient)

Comment: It is possible, but as far as I know you can't specify `DefaultRequestHeaders`  when doing curly brace instantiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use resolve method for that

```
builder.Register(l => new RandomObject(l.Resolve<HttpClient>(), "randomString").As<IRandomObject>();
```

Comment: This is it. I thought that you needed to instantiate a new `ILifetimeScope` object in order to call `Resolve()`, but now I know better! Thanks.